# c# - How to create an array with offsets between its values

Tags: c#, arrays

I don't really know what this is called.

I have a map generator object, and something to generate my vertices. I figured I could improve performance if I used an array that is the size of the map times 4, because each tile has 4 sides.

Basically, what I want is this:

```
array[0] = value.w
array[1] = value.x
array[2] = value.y
array[3] = value.z

array[4] = empty
array[5] = empty
array[6] = empty
array[7] = empty
```

Let's say I have a 32x32 map. 32x32 = 1024. 1024 tiles with the size of 32x32. I have this, at the moment:

```
int[] myValArray = new int[4096];
for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 32; j++)
    {

        myValArray[i * j] = 0;
        myValArray[i * j + 1] = 1;
        myValArray[i * j + 2] = 2;
        myValArray[i * j + 3] = 3;
    }
}
```

However, this wont work. What am I doing wrong? What would be the best way to have offsets in an array?

I tried different methods, but none did work. Such as:
    [i * j * 1]
    [i * j * 4]
    [i * j + 4]

Comment: Why are you allocating the array inside the inner most loop? Shouldn't it be allocated outside both the loops?

Comment: Oh yes, sorry. My bad! Fixed it :p

Comment: Also if you want null-values in the array you should use an array of Nullable<int> like so: `int?[] myValArray = new int?[4096];`

Comment: I don't know what is this (as in, name). I need something that each index is offset by 4.

Comment: I don't understand why you are using nested loops for a `1-D` array.  For one thing, when `i = 0`, you are going to be writing to the same 4 indexes (0, 1, 2, 3) 32 times.

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for something like `myValArray[(i * 32) +  (j * 4) + 1] = 1;`?  But that's really weird.  Just use a `2D` or other better structure.

Comment: @ryanyuyu that's why an offset is needed. each value will be offset by 4, so the total count of actual values is 1024.

Comment: Why do you need an array of int? If you are attempting to get a memory layout, whereby the `w`, `x`, `y` and `z` fields are stored sequentially, you could create a `struct` with these four fields (i.e.. `struct Vertex`) and create an array of vertices: `Vertex[] myVertexArray`

Comment: @Alex I know! The object I'm actually using is a VertexC1P3T2 (3x4 byte = position, 1x4 byte = color, 2x4 byte = texture coords). I used int in the example because it's easier.

Comment: That's a total of 6 ints, not 4. It appears the `int` example did not make it easier. You may want to edit your question by adding a description of the actual thing you wish to achieve, such as mapping `VertexC1P3T2`  to some output shape of `Z` in order to be able to do `X` with this output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your indexing is all messed up.  I'm assuming you want to consider a "row" a consecutive group of 32 sets of 4 coordinates (128 entries).

Your current code does not properly initialize each row.  Look at this inner loop:

```
for (int j = 0; j < 32; j++)
{
    myValArray[i * j] = 0;
    myValArray[i * j + 1] = 1;
    myValArray[i * j + 2] = 2;
    myValArray[i * j + 3] = 3;
}
```

When i = 0, you produce `[0 * j + 1]` which is always `1`.  You are constantly assigning to indexes `0, 1, 2, 3` over and over 32 times.

Likewise for `i = 1` you produce the indexes `(0, 1, 2, 3)` on the first iteration, then `(1, 2, 3, 4)` then (`2, 3, 4, 5)`...

Change this to actually leverage the setup of your 32x32 array.

```
for (int j = 0; j < 32; j++)
{
    int rowOffset = (i * 32 * 4);
    int columnOffset = (j * 4);
    myValArray[rowOffset + columnOffset + 0] = 0;
    myValArray[rowOffset + columnOffset + 1] = 1;
    myValArray[rowOffset + columnOffset + 2] = 2;
    myValArray[rowOffset + columnOffset + 3] = 3;
}
```

Here is a [.NET fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/F0jeBX) demonstrating how your indexing is going wrong.

If you decided to group the 4 values into a single object, you wouldn't need the `*4`.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to initialize myValArray outside of your loops, or it will get reset every time.

If you want to assign the value for every four elements, you only need one for loop. Just increment it by 4 each time:

```
int[] myValArray = new int[4096];
for (int i = 0; i < 4092; i = i + 4)
{
    myValArray[i] = 0;
    myValArray[i + 1] = 1;
    myValArray[i + 2] = 2;
    myValArray[i + 3] = 3;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Remove int[] myValArray = new int[4096]; to the outside of the loops
You will lose any changes you are making since it is recreated everytime, except the last one.